# ARM Template deployment does not remove old pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I'm deploying my data factory using ARM Templates. When I delete a pipeline, the old version is not deleted from the target environment. The same happens with renaming, my target environment then contains a pipeline with the old and AND a pipeline with the new name.

How do I delete old pipelines with ARM Template deployments?

Note: I only want to delete the orphaned pipelines inside the data factory, not wipe out the entire data factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete pipelines inside the data factory, you need to run the script published by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#sample-prepostdeployment-script).

Note that this requires the use of the new Azure "Az" powershell modules, if you are using Azure DevOps requires the use of the preview V4 powershell tasks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the differences between the pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts? It's not very clear from the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved it by leveraging an extension in the marketplace called [Azure Data Factory](https://github.com/liprec/vsts-publish-adf). Within it are various tasks, one of which is called 'Azure Data Factory Delete Items'. I use that before executing the ARM template task from Microsoft and ultimetly I am left with a data factory pipeline that does not contain orphaned pipelines/datasets/linked_services/etc.
[image: Pipeline Tasks]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and followed Neil P's suggestion and looked at creating a post deployment script to remove the items. I was already using CI based on the arm template, so this extended my original CI.

As of this writing, Microsoft's power-shell script does work correctly for ADF V2.

Honestly, the approach right now is a little convoluted. I had to set up two branch artifacts. One looks at adf_publish and one that looks at master. adf_publish triggers the release pipeline, master handles the powershell script.

[image]

Then, I created a deployment powershell script in my repo on the master branch
[image].

After that, I updated the release pipeline to include the powershell script after the resource was updated. Note that I had to reference the ARMTemplateForFactory.json directly to get the script to work.

[image]

Everything worked as expected and the downstream QA release has updated properly and removed obsolete pipelines, etc.

Comment: I have a follow-up comment for this solution - it will not work if the resource you are using is locked from deletion. In order to use this, I have to have my admin team allow the resource lock to be removed, update with CI and then re-lock.

This is how they are protecting production assets, so it makes sense but does not ease deployment.