# ADF ARM Template doesn't appear to include the factory itself

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I was in the process of configuring DevOps to deploy my Dev ADF to the UAT ADF instance.

I had come across the standard issue of the deploy not deleting out-dated pipelines, and attempted to use "Complete" deployment mode to resolve that.

Whereupon DevOps entirely deleted the UAT ADF instance!

Looking further at the docs, it appears that [this is the expected behaviour if the factories are not in the ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/complete-mode-deletion#microsoftdatafactory).
And looking at my ARM Template (generated entirely by ADF, and with [AFAIK] entirely standard settings), it confirms that the factory itself is NOT amongst the documented resources to be created.

This seems ... odd.

---

**Am I missing something?**
How do I get the factory to be included in the ARM Template?

Or alternatively, how can I use the "Complete" deployment mode without it deleting the target ADF instance?

Note that the reason I *don't* want to use the ["define a separate script to solve this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304085/arm-template-deployment-does-not-remove-old-pipelines) approach, is that it seems excessively complex when that the "Complete" mode sounds like it should do exactly what I want :) (If it weren't for this one oddity about deleting the factory)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I've run into this issue before.  To circumnavigate it this I recommend creating a core ARM template that would contain the Data Factory and any necessary linked services solely used by Data Factory.  This will ensure the "infrastructure/connections" are deployed when creating a new instance.

If you are following [Azure Data Factory CI/CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) this would be an additional Azure Resource Group Deployment task before the Pipelines are deployed and reference the ARM template which should be in a separate repository.

Here's a template for Data Factory w/ Log Analytics to get you started.  I included Log Analytics as most people don't realize about Log retention until they need it. Plus it's a best practices.  Just update the system name as this will create a naming standard of adf-systemName-environment-regionAbrviation.  The region abbreviation is dynamic based upon the object and will look up agianst the resource group.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "environment": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": "Name of the environment being deployed to"
        },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
    },
    "variables": {
        "systemName": "DataFactoryBaseName",
    "regionReference": {
      "centralus": "cus",
      "eastus": "eus",
      "westus": "wus"
    },
    "dataFactoryName": "[toLower(concat('adf-', variables('systemName'),'-', parameters('environment'),'-',variables('regionDeployment')))]",
    "logAnalyticsName": "[toLower(concat('law-', variables('systemName'),'-', parameters('environment'),'-',variables('regionDeployment')))]",
    "regionDeployment": "[toLower(variables('regionReference')[parameters('location')])]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
  "name": "[variables('dataFactoryName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": {
        "displayName": "Data Factory",
        "ProjectName": "[variables('systemName')]",
        "Environment":"[parameters('environment')]"
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  }
},
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
      "name": "[variables('logAnalyticsName')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Log Analytics",
        "ProjectName": "[variables('systemName')]",
        "Environment":"[parameters('environment')]"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2020-03-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]"
    },
        {
      "type": "microsoft.datafactory/factories/providers/diagnosticsettings",
      "name": "[concat(variables('dataFactoryName'),'/Microsoft.Insights/diagnostics')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceID('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces',variables('logAnalyticsName'))]",
        "[resourceID('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories',variables('dataFactoryName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "diagnostics",
        "workspaceId": "[resourceID('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces',variables('logAnalyticsName'))]",
        "logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "PipelineRuns",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "enabled": false,
              "days": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "TriggerRuns",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "enabled": false,
              "days": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "ActivityRuns",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "enabled": false,
              "days": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "category": "AllMetrics",
            "timeGrain": "PT1M",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "enabled": false,
              "days": 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ugh, yuck :( How disappointing. I don't suppose you know any way to generate the initial Template for those things, from an existing Factory?

Comment: @Brondahl Updated the answer to include one.

Comment: @Brondahl if this was helpful please upvote the answer or provide feedback on what else can be provided.

Comment: I will once I've had a chance to test it :D Alas I don't get direct control over my Azure context, so when I first screwed this up and deleted the ADF instance I had to get "The Azure Platform Team" to provision me a replacement. Which then means that I can sensibly test alternatives, in case they also delete the target. I'm planning to try to set up a What-If DevOps pipeline which should tell me whether this works.